# Google Play Services - which min sdk to use

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have created an app but when I tried to test it on my minsdk which is API 21, google play services won't work.

The error I get is `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4:`.

I followed the [setup guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), which means I have set my Google Play Services libs to version 11.8.0, it says I just have to use Android 4.2.2 which is API 17.

My `compileSdkVersion` is set to 27.

Is there something big I am misunderstanding here on how the compiling works? The app works fine on API 26 and 25, but fails when I try using it on API 24, with the same error as with API 21.

My build.gradle file looks like this.
https://gist.github.com/uruloke/f2f71dd6318d365cd53d74c274cd8523

When using the `GoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn()` from the `addOnFailureListener`, I get the following exception

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzt.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Also if I try to use the `GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()`, no intent is shown when starting it, but in my `onActivityResult`, I get an result which is non-successful, but with an empty status message

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.d(TAG, result.getStatus().toString());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            menuFragment.updateUi(signedInAccount);
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = "Failed to sign in to Play Games. Maybe try updating it?";
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The Android emulator with an AVD **that runs the Google APIs platform** based on Android 4.2.2 or higher." Did you pick the right image?

Comment: Play services works with minSdk 9+

Comment: @EugenPechanec My emulator is running with Google API's. https://i.imgur.com/OrsIIqc.png

Comment: @TimCastelijns ...on a real device. uruloke, please post the whole exception and your app's build.gradle.

Comment: @EugenPechanec just updated my question with the information.

Comment: Are you sure your emulator has latest Google Play Service installed? Check version, if it's lower than you used in your app, it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `public static final int SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`
>
> The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in.  The client may choose to continue without using the API. Alternately, **if `hasResolution()` returns true the client may call `startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)` to prompt the user to sign in**. After the sign in activity returns with `RESULT_OK` further attempts should succeed.
>
> Constant Value: 4

Source: [CommonStatusCodes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes), emphasis mine

It looks like  `silentSignIn` only works if you're signed in to Google on the device, to be precise:

> We attempt to sign users in if:
>
> - There is one and only one matching account on the device that has previously signed in to your application, and
> - the user previously granted all of the scopes your app is requesting for this sign in.

Source: [GoogleSignInApi#silentSignIn](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#silentSignIn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient))

Comment: Oh, couldn't find the status codes, thanks!

Having another problem now though, i started the signInIntent, but it doesn't launch the signInIntent, again it works on newer API's (25, 26), but not on older API's (24, 21). 
`Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}`

Comment: @uruloke That's code for [SIGN_IN_CANCELLED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInStatusCodes.html#SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) and that's definitely weird. Are you trying only in an emulator? Can you try it on a real Android 5-7 device?

Comment: I should be able to test it later today on an Android 5 device, right now I only have an 8.1 device at my disposal.

Comment: The problem was that the emulator didn't have Google Play Store installed, it worked fine on a real device, Thanks for the help!